# Plotly -Round hover decimals in charts

Tags: python, plotly

How do you round numbers for display in a plotly graph?  I included an MRE below.  Essentially I wanted rounded numbers to appear when the user hovers over the bar.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'num': [1, 2, 3],
                   'sqrt': pd.Series([1, 2, 3]) ** 0.5})
fig = px.bar(df, x='num', y='sqrt', title='Square root')
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it two ways like this:

METHOD-1: Using `pd.series.round` function.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'num': [1, 2, 3],
                   'sqrt': (pd.Series([1, 2, 3]) ** 0.5).round(2)})
fig = px.bar(df, x='num', y='sqrt', title='Square root')
fig.show()
```

METHOD-2: Using python builtin `round` function. For this to work I will have to use `list comprehension` instead of `pandas series`. As series doesn't support it directly.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'num': [1, 2, 3],
                   'sqrt': [round(x**(1/2),2) for x in [1,2,3]]})
fig = px.bar(df, x='num', y='sqrt', title='Square root')
fig.show()
```

**EDIT**:

METHOD-3: As answered by @M. Forsythe below you can also do it using `hover_data` parameter of plotly.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'num': [1, 2, 3],
                   'sqrt': pd.Series([1, 2, 3]) ** 0.5})
fig = px.bar(df, x='num', y='sqrt', title='Square root',hover_data={'sqrt':':.2f'})
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

For plotly express this is covered in the hover format documentation in the section titled “Disabling or customizing hover of columns in plotly express” (https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/)

Note that the format strings are d3 format strings, not python f-string formats.

Answer (score 1):

To round your numbers, you can use `r` with `hover_data` like that:

```
fig = px.bar(df, x='num', y='sqrt', hover_data={'sqrt':':.3r'})
```